# Error in initializing MPI cluster with snowfall R

Tags: r, mpi

I'm trying to initializing MPI cluster with snowfall R. I use

```
> sfInit(parallel = TRUE, cpus = 39,   type = "MPI")
```

then I have

```
> sfInit(parallel = TRUE, cpus = 39,   type = "MPI")
Library Rmpi loaded.
Error in makeMPIcluster(.sfOption$nodes, outfile = tmp, homogenous = TRUE,  : 
  MPI cluster of size 38 already running
Error in sfInit(parallel = TRUE, cpus = 39, type = "MPI") : 
  Starting of snow cluster failed! Error in makeMPIcluster(.sfOption$nodes, outfile = tmp, homogenous = TRUE,  : 
  MPI cluster of size 38 already running
 Error in makeMPIcluster(.sfOption$nodes, outfile = tmp, homogenous = TRUE,  : 
  MPI cluster of size 38 already running
Execution halted
```

Any idea how to fix this error ? thank you